# how to daily rolling balance in post gresql using txn table

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, finance, recursive-query

The three tables being used here are

1) customer - cust_id , email

2) account - cust_id, account_id, account_balance

3) Txn - txn_id, account_id, timestamp, credit/debit, amount

i need to calculate the account balance of xyz@abc.com for the past 10 days on a daily basis

eg: 
Date | balance

10/6 |   100

09/6 |  100

08/6 |   250

07/6 |  200

.
.

01/6 |  200

txn table would look like this for the above example

account id | txn id  | time_stamp | type  | amount

1    | 4   | 08/6  |  credit | 50

1    | 5   | 09/6  |  debit  | 150

i wrote the following code by creating another table containing daily_total txns as daily_txn, still only second row is getting generated

`with cte as (
      select dates, daily_balance, daily_total, row_number() over (order by dates desc) as seqnum
      from Daily_txn
     )
select t.dates, t.daily_total, tprev.daily_balance - coalesce(tprev.daily_total, 0) as new_balance
from cte t left outer join
     cte tprev
     on t.seqnum = tprev.seqnum + 1;`

Comment: Please reenter the above as text. It makes it easier to follow and allows folks to use the data.  Though I'm guessing the answer is going to involve window functions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html

Comment: i wrote the following code by creating another table containing daily_total txns as daily_txn, still only second row is getting generated

with cte as (
      select dates, daily_balance, daily_total, row_number() over (order by dates desc) as seqnum
      from Daily_txn
     )
select t.dates, t.daily_total, tprev.daily_balance - coalesce(tprev.daily_total, 0) as new_balance
from cte t left outer join
     cte tprev
     on t.seqnum = tprev.seqnum + 1;